# What is the least disruptive way to display ads in a mobile application

Tags: design-patterns, mobile-application, advertisement

From this question I have understood popup ads are annoying to the end-user: 
[When is the best time to display ads in phone applications](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99546/when-is-the-best-time-to-display-ads-in-phone-applications)

Could you explain how one can generate a little revenue with ads without abusing the user experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

- If you have a (modal) screen where a user needs to wait until certain information is loaded, submitted or calculated, you can show an advertisement underneath a progress bar. You can compare this to ads on railway stations.
- If your main screen consists of a list (e.g. news items), grid (e.g. photos) or something like a timeline, consider showing advertisements which 'blend' into the rest of the content. Do make sure that it is easy to see that they are advertisements (e.g. with an extra icon or different outline), otherwise your users will feel tricked.

Answer (score 2):

If I was in your positon I would go with some of next options: 
 
 - very bottom 10 - 15% of the screen, without covering important functionalities, and with clear X to close / minimize 
 - if some important functionalities are on the bottom, same thing mentioned just on top 
 
 - "Floating action button". If you google this, you will see in material design it is a button on far bottom right of the screen floating with scrolling. I saw many listing sites use it as a button to toggle pop up commercial. Which then can easily be closed, and in original it is not blocking the content or functionalities.